# Is there a way to automatically reformat Blend's XAML view?

Tags: xaml, expression-blend

Blend tends to create its XAML in very long lines.

Is there a way to reformat it so that the properties of each element are lined up vertically under each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using Visual Studio:

> Change the default settings for XAML documents, and then use CTRL+E,D (Edit | Advanced | Format Document) or CTRL+E,F (Edit | Advanced | Format Selection).

http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/06/07/xaml-markup-formatting-in-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a feature in Blend that will autoformat XAML. I usually do xaml formatting with Visual Studio.

Another option is to paste your XAML into Kaxaml and use its excellent XAML scrubber, then paste the result back into Blend.
You can see a demo on Channel9: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/Kaxaml/

Answer (score 0):

Or try xaml styler hosted at http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/  for visual studio 2010. If you ever used Kaxaml's Xaml Scrubber and you like it, then you could think of this extension is the "Xaml Scrubber" for Visual Studio.

Check http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/ for feature highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Visual Studio. (I'm using 2012).

1. Tools > Options > Xaml Styler (at the bottom)
2. Under **Misc**
3. Set `Beautify on saving xaml` to FALSE

You can now save your xaml however you like, and it will stay like that.